# How can I learn the Backstab enchantment in Skyrim through the console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to learn the backstab enchantment via the console, but none of the items that have it can be disenchanted, so I can't simply spawn it in. How do I learn the enchantment directly? The code for the enchantment is `ff15c`.

Clarification: `playerenchantobject` is *not* the command I am looking for. I am asking how to *learn* enchants that cannot be disenchanted, I am not asking about how to enchant things via console. When you enchant from console, there are many things you cannot do, such as renaming the item, proper enchantment scaling, and adjusting the amount of charge a weapon has.

Second clarification: `player.additem refid [enchantment id]` is NOT the syntax of the command, please test the command before answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

Some background information to clarify the request (for users other than the OP): the few in-game items that feature the [Backstab](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Backstab) enchantment (like the Shrouded Gloves) [cannot be disenchanted](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Backstab#Enchanting).
Even summoning items with this enchantment (e.g. `playerenchantobject 261C1 ff15c` to summon plain gloves "*of Backstabbing*") and trying to disenchant them doesn't work (the player receives the message "*The enchantment on this item is already known*").

---

And so **the Backstab enchantment can't be learned through the console** (unless there are commands that are currently unknown), but there are other ways.

- The easiest way to solve the matter is to use a mod, like [Learn Backstab Enchantment](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/6296).
  The author [mentions what they did](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?showtopic=5174905/#entry65048521) in the related thread on the Nexusmods forum:

  > All I did was literally remove the "cannot disenchant" flag from that piece of gear.

  It's easy to do the same yourself in the Creation Kit, but you'll still have to load an .esp to get the changes in-game, so you might as well download this one and save yourself some time. In the Creation Kit, open the object you'd like to be able to disenchant, and remove the `MagicDisallowEnchanting` keyword:

  [image: Shrouded Gloves item in the Creation Kit, with the MagicDisallowEnchanting keyword highlighted]
- Another method is to use [TES5Edit](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25859) (or [SSEEdit](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/164) for the Special Edition of Skyrim) instead of the Creation Kit.
  Open TES5Edit, let it load everything up. Then fill in FormID `D2843` for the Shrouded Gloves (or look for IDs of the other items [here](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Backstab#Enchanting)). After hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and allowing SSEEdit to load the right item, you can see and edit its properties on the right side. To make changes, you first need to <kbd>right-click</kbd> the object, and select *Copy as override (with overwriting) into...*:

  [image]

  And create a new .esp file:

  [image]

  Look for the *KWDA - Keywords* header, and remove `MagicDisallowEnchanting` **from the column underneath your newly created .esp file**, so you'll end up with the following situation (yellow indicates a change, and the NULL Reference simply implies the keyword is gone):

  [image]

  Save, making sure your new file is selected in the pop-up menu:

  [image]

  Press OK. Load it up in Skyrim, and enter your game (I used the console command `player.additem D2843 1` to add a pair of the gloves to my inventory). Et voilà:

  [image: "You learned the Backstab enchantment" message in Skyrim]